# Flutter Android build is not showing resource id for Appium

Tags: android, flutter, appium

> Problem

In Flutter android build

When trying to test app with Appium **resource id** is coming up empty though the semantic label has been provided to the Widget.

In iOS I am getting accessibility id properly.

Example widget like Text

```
Text('Some text', semanticsLabel: 'text_field');
```

> Question

Is there any fix to this issue?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @Sikandar: Tried but couldn't get resource id for android. iOS is working well.

Comment: There is an open issue about this on flutter https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17988